# PHP Facebook SDK 4.0 post as a page server to server

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm trying to post as a page on a Facebook page since 6 days without success, which is really frustrating using new facebook SDK 4.0.4.

I'm under PHP 5.4 (as requested by Facebook 4.0 SDK version).
I already read some times all the facebook documentation (which isn't so clear) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0.

For logging-in:

```
<?php

require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookServerException.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\FacebookServerException;



        session_start();


        // init app with app id and secret
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($site["facebook_appid"],$site["facebook_appsecret"] );

        // login helper with redirect_uri
        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($site["url"].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        // see if a existing session exists
        if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
          // create new session from saved access_token
          $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

          // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
          try {
            if ( !$session->validate() ) {
              $session = null;
            }
          } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            // catch any exceptions
            $session = null;
          }
           echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://yourwebsite.com/app/logout.php' ) . '">Logout</a>';
        } else {
          // no session exists

          try {
            $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
          } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
            // When Facebook returns an error
          } catch( Exception $ex ) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            echo $ex->message;
          }

          echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends' , 'publish_stream', 'manage_pages', 'publish_actions', 'status_update', 'user_likes ',  'photo_upload') ) . '">Login</a>';


        }



///////////////////////////
// SHORT LIVED TOKEN
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, "GET", "/".$site["facebook_appid"]."/accounts?access_token=".$site["facebook_appid"]."|".$site["facebook_appsecret"]."&grant_type=client_credentials" );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();


  if (DebugMode) e($graphObject);

    $site['facebook_short-lived_access_token'] =  $graphObject['data'][0]->access_token;

////////////////////////

///////////////////////////
// LONG LIVED TOKEN
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, "GET", "/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=".$site["facebook_appid"]."&client_secret=".$site["facebook_appsecret"]."&fb_exchange_token=" .$site['facebook_short-lived_access_token']);
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();


  if (DebugMode) e($graphObject);

    $site['facebook_long-lived_access_token'] =  $graphObject['access_token'];
    $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $site['facebook_long-lived_access_token'];

    if (DebugMode) e($site['facebook_long-lived_access_token']);

?>
```

And for publishing:

```
<?php

require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( BaseRoot. '/include/scripts/facebook_php_sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookPermissionException.php' );


use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookPermissionException;


if($session) {


  try {
    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'POST', "/".$site["facebook_page_id"]."/feed",
      array(
        'access_token' => $_SESSION['fb_token'],
        'link' => $site["url"].'/url',
        'name' => 'link name',
        'caption' => 'link caption',
        'description' => 'link description',
        'picture' => $site["url"].'/alpha.png',
        'message' => 'User provided message'
      )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

    echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');

  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

  }   

}

?>
```

I first get a session ID, then request and obtain a short-lived token, with which i request and obtain a long-lived token (60 days validity). Then I continue with the publish script using the last obtained token.
I submit a post and it return back a post-id like it works, but nothing on the page, nothing in my personal Facebook history.

My application is in development mode and was not reviewed by Facebook, but it seems to not be necessary anymore: http://www.nextscripts.com/known-issues/facebook-issues/

Any idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: No one can help... Is this problem really don't have any solution? 40 days and 274 view later, still not the shadow of an answer...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not realy into the facebook SDK, but I noticed one line that I suspect to be incorrect:

```
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends' , 'publish_stream', 'manage_pages', 'publish_actions', 'status_update', 'user_likes ',  'photo_upload') ) . '">Login</a>';
```

The facebook documentation about this function can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/).
It states that you schould, to ask for extra permissions, give an array with the index 'scope' and as value in string with a comma between every permission you want to request instead of an array with indexes called to permission but without any data in it. I suspect it should be something like:

```
$helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'public_profile,email,user_friens,publish_stream,<and so on>'));
```

I hope this helps you.